# Sort a list of start and end points strings

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to solve a simple problem in python but i'm really struggling.

I have a list of strings that looks like this:

```
["1->5","2->4","5->3","3->2"]
```

where the first number before the arrow represents the start point and the number after the finish point. Either string in the list represents one movement, (1->5 started from 1 and went to 5)

The goal is to create a single line that resume all the list. In the example above, the output would be:

1 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4

which is the "full movement"

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I suggest converting the input into a dictionary of `start: end` items. Then you can easily get the next step in the path by looking up the end point in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```py
strings = ["1->5", "2->4", "5->3", "3->2"]
moves = dict(string.split("->") for string in reversed(strings))
stations = list(moves.popitem())
while end := moves.pop(stations[-1], False):
    stations.append(end)
result = " -> ".join(stations)  # For the sample: '1 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4'
```

Transform the splitted strings into a dictionary `moves`, in reversed order. Pop the last key-value tuple (from the first string) and make a list `stations` out of it. Then go through the `moves` as long as possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Convert it to a graph, then record your traversal of the graph:**

```
# Make a graph:
lst = ["1->5","2->4","5->3","3->2"]
graph = {move.split("->")[0]: move.split("->")[1] for move in lst}  # {'1': '5', '2': '4', '5': '3', '3': '2'}

# Traverse graph:
start = "1"  # Starting point
result= [int(start)]
val = graph[start]
while val:
    result.append(int(val))  # I assume you want integers.
    val = graph.get(val)

print(result)  # [1, 5, 3, 2, 4]
```

This code converts your list to the graph `{'1': '5', '2': '4', '5': '3', '3': '2'}` using a dict comprehension, and then traverses it while recording the path it took in `result`. You can change the `start` variable to wherever you'd like to start.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
# Your list
l = ["1->5","2->4","5->3","3->2"]

# Create a dictionary of your pairs
dct = {int(i[0]) : int(i[1]) for i in [i.split("->") for i in l]}
# {1: 5, 2: 4, 5: 3, 3: 2}

# This will contain the result.
new_list = []

# Manually set the last stop to the first int of the first pair.
last_stop = int(l[0].split("->")[0])

# and add it to the new_list
new_list.append(last_stop)

# Iterate for (len(l)), finding the value for the last stop, and add it to new_list. 
for i in range(len(l)):
    next_value = dct[last_stop]
    new_list.append(next_value)
    last_stop = next_value

print(new_list)
# [1, 5, 3, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could link the path in one pass by keeping track of partially linked chains in two dictionaries.  One that indexes the first number in a chain and one to index the chains by their last number. After going through each links to connect sub-chains together, the last chain connected should have all the links together.

```
links  = ["1->5","2->4","5->3","3->2"]

starts = dict() # index on first number of chain
ends   = dict() # index on last number of same chains
for link in links:
    s,e = link.split("->")                       # start and end of link 
    chain  = ends.pop(s,[s]) + starts.pop(e,[e]) # link 2 chains
    starts[chain[0]] = ends[chain[-1]] = chain   # update indexing

print(*chain,sep="->") # last chain is the result
# 1->5->3->2->4
```

Alternatively, you could use a dictionary to map each number to the next number.  Then find the starting point using set differences (between the starting and ending numbers).  The link chain can be assembled by following through the next numbers in the dictionary until there are no next number (for the last entry in the chain):

```
links  = ["1->5","2->4","5->3","3->2"]

nextNum  = dict(link.split("->") for link in links)     # map to next numbers
chain    = list(set(nextNum)-set(nextNum.values()))[:1] # first number
chain.extend(filter(None,map(nextNum.get,chain)))       # follow links to end

print(*chain,sep="->")
# 1->5->3->2->4
```